# Set Up 3 Tier SP 2016 farm in AWS

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, installation, sql, configuration-wizard, aws

I'm currently creating a 3 tier SP 2016 farm in AWS.

I was updated that AWS doesn't have SQL Servers and SQL is managed by RDS Engine.

I was given a SQL endpoint string instead of SQL server name.

Also AWS DBs doesn't have dbcreator, sysadmin, public, securityadmin roles.

How do I run the product configuration wizard using SQL end point string and create the config DBs?

I couldn't find any documentation on installing SharePoint on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to create your own SQL server.  SharePoint on prem is designed for SQL on prem.  It's definitely going to fall under unsupported by Microsoft if you do manage to get it working anyways.

Answer (score 0):

AWS team configured that RDS is not supported for SharePoint on prem configuration. Planning for SQL server on top on EC2 now

Answer (score 0):

Amazon definitely has SQL instances.

https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/amis/

SharePoint doesn't care *where* your databases are as long as they are on the same domain.

Comment: That is on prem SQL.  Those are machine images of Windows with different versions of SQL included.